# ¿COMO PUEDO VALIDAR UN INPUT PARA QUE SOLO ACEPTE LAS VOCALES?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

**Necesito usar lo mpas básico, for, if,else,arrays.**

Comment: Bienvenida, te recomiendo hagas el [tour] para que conozcas un poco más acerca del sitio, así mismo leer [ask] para que tus preguntas sean mejor recibidas por la comunidad, se necesita de un avance y el error en concreto para que se te pueda ayudar, de no ser así se cerrará tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo puedes hacer directamente con html5 con el atributo partenr

esto se vería así

```html
<form name="formulario" method="post">
  
  <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Vocales"
         required pattern="[AEIOUaeiou]{5,40}"
         title="Letras. Tamaño mínimo: 5. Tamaño máximo: 40">
</form>
```

Deberías de mostrar el código que ya tienes, para orientarte mejor. Dado que si lo piensas hacer con estructuras de control es más complejo. Lo que necesitas se resume a evaluar una expresión regular.

aquí te va una idea extra

```js
function evelua_texto(e){
  for(let a in e.value.split('')){
     switch (e.value.split('')[a]) {
        case 'a':
            correcto();
            break;
        case 'e':
            correcto();
            break;
        case 'i':
            correcto();
            break;
        case '0':
            correcto();
            break;
        case 'u':
            correcto();
            break;
        default:
        error();
            break;
    }
  }
}

function error(){
  var el = document.getElementById('error');
  el.innerText ="Este texto incluye valores no permitidos";
}

function correcto(){
  var el = document.getElementById('error');
  el.innerText = "correcto";
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" placeholder="volcales" onKeyUp="evelua_texto(this)">
     
<div id="error" />
```

Como sea espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: No crees que es locura no?